# Data link layer - CRC what does divide by 1 + x mean?

Tags: networking, crc

Can someone please explain what this part of **CRC** codes from Tannenbaum *computer networks* means!

> If there has been a single-bit error, E(x) = x^i , where i determines which bit is
>   in error. If G(x) contains two or more terms, it will never divide into E(x), so all
>   single-bit errors will be detected.

And

> If there have been two isolated single-bit errors, E(x) = x^i + x^j , where i > j.
>   Alternatively, this can be written as E(x) = x^j (x^(i − j) + 1). If we assume that G(x)
>   is not divisible by x, a sufficient condition for all double errors to be detected is
>   that G(x) does not divide x ^k + 1 for any k up to the maximum value of i − j (i.e.,
>   up to the maximum frame length). Simple, low-degree polynomials that give pro-
>   tection to long frames are known. For example, x ^15 + x ^14 + 1 will not divide
>   x ^k + 1 for any value of k below 32,768.

Please post in simple terms so I can understand it a bit more!. **EXAMPLEs** are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A message is a sequence of bits. You can convert any sequence of bits into a polynomial by just making each bit the coefficient of 1, x, x<sup>2</sup>, etc. starting with the first bit. So 100101 becomes 1+x<sup>3</sup>+x<sup>5</sup>.

You can make these polynomials useful by considering their coefficients to be members of the simplest finite field, [GF(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)), which consists only of the elements 0 and 1. There addition is the exclusive-or operation and multiplication is the and operation.

Now you can do all the things you did with polynomials in high school, but where the coefficients are over GF(2). So 1+x added to x+x<sup>2</sup> becomes 1+x<sup>2</sup>. 1+x times 1+x becomes 1+x<sup>2</sup>. (Work it out.)

Cyclic Redundancy Checks (CRCs) are derived from this approach to binary message arithmetic, where a message converted to a polynomial is divided by a special constant polynomial whose degree is the number of bits in the CRC. Then the coefficients of the remainder of that polynomial division is the CRC of that message.

Read [Ross William's CRC tutorial](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) for more. (Real CRCs are not just that remainder, but you'll see.)